# Conceptual Relationship Between "River" (יאר) and "Light" (אור)

Tags: hebrew, drush

There seems to be a relationship between the words "river" (יאר) and light (אור), that is only underscored by the fact that "river" in Hebrew (נהר) is essentially the same word as "light" in Aramaic (נהרא).

I am looking for a conceptual relationship (preferably, on the level of דרוש) between the two concepts, something that would explain their coming from very related roots in לשון הקדש, as developed in classical Jewish sources (Talmud, Rishonim, Acharonim).

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should ask this here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage

Comment: @msh210 I was looking for a drush connecting the two words, which seems directly a part of the Jewish learning. It wasn't an etymology question :). How else can I ask it to get it answered? The link Ariel posted above seems, unfortunately, discussion amongst academics about Hebrew, which I am not interested in... I'm looking for drush, conceptual connection between the ideas. Thank you.

Comment: @Ariel, [Here's](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) how Area51 works. It doesn't host Q&A sites; it hosts proposals for sites. Indeed, the definition process depends on people posting and voting on potential questions that could populated the proposed site, but they're for sample purposes only and do not get answered there.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question! I think there is definitely a midrashic connection (whereas an etymological connection would exist not for Ye'or-or, but probably for nahar-nahara).

Melila Hellner-Eshed's phenomenal book "[A River Flows from Eden](http://books.google.ca/books?id=EYqu1TCqfyAC&pg=PA237)" explores the significance of that verse ([Genesis 2:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm)) in Qabbalistic thought, and discusses throughout her book the thematic connection between rivers and light — an especially prominent concern in the Zohar, whose very name means 'light'. She argues that the "river" that flows from "Eden" to "the garden", for the Qabbalists, was the flow of divine blessing from the divine reality into our world. She cites on pp. 237-238 a section of Zohar linking Genesis 2:10 to [Daniel 12:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3412.htm), "the wise will shine as the brightness [*zohar*] of the firmament". The radiance, the Zohar says, is "the shining [nehiru] and sparkling of the river [nahara]". Hellner-Eshed explains that "'the radiance of the sky' is in fact the river that flows from Eden, sparkling as a stream of light. This streaming light is that which radiates from the kabbalists... The radiance, so important to the work that bears this name, is in fact the streaming of the river... They view the entire sky as a kind of river (perhaps because of the ever-changing position of the stars) and within this sky they identify a river of light [nahar dinur], the Milky Way, a river that flows from the depths of the sky and pours fourth its plenty on the world. Thus Rabbi Abba explains: 'Who is the expanse illuminating Earth? You must admit, this is the river flowing forth from Eden, as is written: A river flows from Eden to water the garden'". She also has an interesting quote [on page 232](http://books.google.ca/books?id=EYqu1TCqfyAC&pg=PA232) from Rabbi Asher ben David on the light-river connection.

She doesn't appear to say anything about the Ye'or-or connection but I think it is related nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Follows is a quote from my own personal notes of a weekly lecture on chumash that I give.

כבר הערנו על זה שששת ימי בראשית נחלקים לשני סדרים של שלשת שלשת ימים, ושהם מקבילים זה לזה. הערנו גם שהיום הראשון יש בו בריאת האור כמו יום הרביעי, ושהאור עומד בראש כל הבריאה והוא יסוד התפתחות כל ששת הימים. 
הערנו גם שהמטר נקרא אור (בר"ר סופכ"ו אמר רבי יוחנן כל אורה שנאמר באליהו אינה אלא ירידת גשמים), וגם לשון נהר ויאר שייכים לאורה, וא"כ אפשר להבין ששלשת הימים הראשונים הם התפתחות אורו של ה' על ידי המים והדשאים הצומחים דרך המים. (ושלשת ימים האחרונים הם התפתחות אור הגשמי והבעלי חיים שיש להם דעת של עצמם השייכים לזה.) אבל להבין את זה צריך מתחלה להבין למה הגשמים ושאר מימות נקראים בלשון אורה, ואיך זה קשור למהות האור ותיקון המים שבשלשת הימים.
ראה ברמב"ן ראש פרשת מקץ שנתקשה למה המטר נקרא אור, והאב"ע על הפסוק באיוב לו ל הן פרש עליו אורו ושרשי הים כסה הביא הפירוש שזה חוזר על הגשמים (וכדברי רבי יוחנן, וכן פירש רש"י שם), והוא חולק על פירוש זה משום שאינו מסכים אל הקשר הזה בין המטר לאור ע"ש. אבל מ"מ גם האב"ע יודה שנהר ויאר שייכים לאורה.
הבה נבין הקשר בין מטר לאור- בדרך אפשר.
וחשך על פני תהום. אפשר להבין את זה כמהות המים בעצם. דהיינו שהמים, הבלתי מתוקנים, הנקוים ביחד במקום אחד, עושים תהום עם חשכת התהום. כן הבינו בשמות רבה פט"ו כ"ב המים קדמה לעולם וכו' המים הרו וילדו אפלה- דהיינו שתולדות המים, בלי תיקון, היא אפלה. במציאות הדברים הפירוש הוא שריבוי מים עושים תהום, הכרוך עם אפלה. עומק משמעות הדבר עוד יבואר.
אפשר להבין גם שהמים הם יסוד של כל המציאות והחיים. כתוב (ירמיה ב יג) כי אתי עזבו מקור מים חיים וגו'. המים הם אלו שעושים אפשרות של חיים. אם כן פסוק ב' של פרשת בראשית פירושו כך- הארץ היתה תהו ובהו- בלי צורה, כי המים לא נתקנו להביא חיים אל העולם, כי השמים (מקום המים) היו חלוקים, חלק התחתון היה תהום וחשכו, וחלק העליון האלקי לא נתקנה עדיין, כי רוח אלקים מרחפת על פני המים (וכמש"ב). המים הבלתי מתוקנים הביאו את חשכת התהום, ולכן הארץ נשאר תהו ובהו.
אם כנים הדברים, המים הבלתי מתוקנים מביאים את החשך, דהיינו שהשפעת המציאות בלי תיקון מביאה את החשך, דהיינו ביטול ההשגה. לכן תיקונו של המציאות, דהיינו המים, הוא עשיית אפשרות שיהיה אור ביחד עם המציאות. המציאות הבלתי מתוקנת ומוגבלת היא חשך, ולכן תיקונו נקרא בלשון אור.
ראה זכריה יד ז והיה לעת ערב יהיה אור והיה ביום ההוא יצאו מים חיים מירושלים וגו', תהלים לו ט מנחל עדניך תשקם כי עמך מקור חיים באורך נראה אור, יחזקאל מג ב כבוד אלקי ישראל בא מדרך הקדים וקולו כקול מים רבים והארץ האירה מכבודו. בשלשת מקומות אלו מוזכר אור ה' עם מי ה'.
על הלויתין כתוב (איוב מא כד) אחריו יאיר נתיב יחשב תהום לשיבה, דהיינו שהלויתן עושה את התהום לבן כאיש זקן. התהום חשך, דהיינו המציאות הבלתי מוגבלת מביא לידי הפסק השגת האמת. לויתן הוא תיקונו של כל המציאות בכללו, דהיינו שריבוי שפע המציאות לא יסתיר את האמת וההשגה. התהום שהוא חשך בראשיתו, לבסוף יאיר.
והענין שאם יש ריבוי השפעה בלי מיעוט, נשכח ה' המשפיע. רק על ידי מיעוט ההשפעה והכרת חסרון ההשפעה יבינו האנשים שכל ההשפעה אינה אלא רצון ה'.
ככל היסוד הזה נמצא בספר אוצרות רמח"ל. ז"ל על הפסוק יקוו המים וגו'
בתחלה היו המים שטוחים על הארץ כולה ולבסוף נקוו אל מקום אחד. סוד הענין, הארץ היא סוד מלכות (דהיינו האפשרות לקבלת השפעה), ובתחלה היו המים על כולה, וזה היה רומז שכל חלקי המלכות היו מלאים שפע להביא לעולם, ובזה לא היו הנבראים יכולים לעמוד, שכשם שאי אפשר לעולם לעמוד על הרע כך אי אפשר לקיים על רוב הטובה, ולכך חלק אחד של המלכות נמלא ממים דהיינו סוד ההשפעה, שלא תהיה חסרה לעולם, וחלק אחד של המלכות תהיה יבשה דהיינו שאורותיה יהיו סתומים, כדי שהעולם יתקיים. אבל עכ"פ גם זה היובש, אם היה לעולם, לא היה אפשר להתקיים, ולכך צריך שגם זה החלק יבוא בו לפעמים השפע, וזה סוד הגשמים הבאים בארץ. ועכ"פ גשמים הרבה למלאות כל העולם זה אינו טוב, שהעולם לא היה יכול לעמוד בו, וזה סוד המבול, שמרוב השפע נולד חרבן. עכ"ל
זכינו להבין שהמים איננו אלא יסוד של כל המציאות וההשפעה של חיים. התהום הוא מקום המים המרובים הבלתי מתוקנים, מה שמביא לידי חשך. ריבוי השפעה ומציאות מחשיך את ידיעת סבת המציאות. תיקונו של המים איננו אלא עשיית המציאות הבלתי מתוקנת, החשוך, למציאות מאירה. לכן המים המתוקנים נקראים אור. שלשת הימים הראשונים הם תיקון האור במציאות, ותיקון מה שנאמר וחשך על פני תהום.
פסוק ו
יהי רקיע וגו'
ביארנו כי ויקרא אלקים לאור יום וגו' הוא האופן איך הבדיל אלקים בין אור לחשך. על ידי קביעת התחומים האלו הוא הבדיל ביניהם. גם קריאת השמות ביום השלישי היא הבדלה בין הים ליבשה (פסחים קד.). ביום שני אין אלקים קורא שמות מיוחדים למים העליונים ולמים התחתונים. הטעם לזה פשוט משום שהרקיע הוא המבדיל ביניהם. גם ההבדל איננו אלא זה שיש מים מתחת לרקיע ויש מים מעל לרקיע. היינו כל ההבדל הוא בגדר יחס המים אל הרקיע.
מהו מים ממעל לרקיע. ראה תהלים קד עטה אור כשלמה נטה שמים כיריעה המקרה במים עליותיו השם עבים רכובו המהלך על כנפי רוח עשה מלאכיו רוחות משרתיו אש להט. מים, עבים, רוחות, ואש להט (ברק). אלו הם תיאור הגשמים ומה שמתלוה אליהם. המים אשר מעל לרקיע איננו אלא המטר. ולמטה מן הרקיע ישנו שאר המים, דהיינו נהר יאר ותהום הים.
נראה איך ראיית יחזקאל בפרק א היא ראיית רקיע זה. לשון רקיע אינו מצוי בתנ"ך, אלא לשון שמים. אבל ביחזקאל א, כאשר נפתחו השמים וראה יחזקאל מראות אלקים, מוזכר לשון רקיע תמיד.

כב ודמות על-ראשי החיה, רקיע, כעין, הקרח הנורא--נטוי על-ראשיהם, מלמעלה.  כג ותחת, הרקיע, כנפיהם ישרות, אשה אל-אחותה:  לאיש, שתים מכסות להנה, ולאיש שתים מכסות להנה, את גויתיהם.  כד ואשמע את-קול כנפיהם כקול מים רבים כקול-שדי, בלכתם--קול המלה, כקול מחנה; בעמדם, תרפינה כנפיהן.  כה ויהי-קול--מעל, לרקיע אשר על-ראשם; בעמדם, תרפינה כנפיהן.  כו וממעל, לרקיע אשר על-ראשם, כמראה אבן-ספיר, דמות כסא; ועל, דמות הכסא, דמות כמראה אדם עליו, מלמעלה.  כז וארא כעין חשמל, כמראה-אש בית-לה סביב, ממראה מתניו, ולמעלה; וממראה מתניו, ולמטה, ראיתי כמראה-אש, ונגה לו סביב.  כח כמראה הקשת אשר יהיה בענן ביום הגשם, כן מראה הנגה סביב--הוא, מראה דמות כבוד-ה'; ואראה ואפל על-פני, ואשמע קול מדבר

לכן אמרו בפרקי דר"א פ"ד רבי אליעזר אומר ואיזה רקיע ברא ביום שני רקיע שעל ראשי החיות שנאמר וגו'. ראה ברד"ל שם שזה משום לשון רקיע שמוזכר במראה יחזקאל. נראה איך ראיית יחזקאל היא על הרקיע הזה ושני מיני מים.
במראה יחזקאל היו שני קולות. קול מתחת לרקיע, מה שהיה כקול מים רבים, וקול מעל לרקיע, מה שדיבר אליו. קול החיות, אלו שמתחת לרקיע, היה כקול מים רבים. כן כתוב גם בפרק מג על כבוד ה'- וקולו כמים רבים. זה סותר, לכאורה, מה שכתוב בתהלים צג מקלות מים רבים אדירים משברי ים אדיר במרום ה'. הכוונה שם בתהלים הוא שקול ה' בשמים הוא יותר אדיר מקולות מים רבים. קול ה' שבשמים שהוא יותר אדיר מקולות מים רבים הוא, לדעתנו, קול הרעם. כן נראה ממש"כ (תהלים כט ג) קול ה' על המים אל הכבוד הרעים ה' על מים רבים. קול ה' הוא קול אדיר של רעם, אדיר יותר ממים רבים. ואילו כאן ביחזקאל קול ה' איננו אלא כקול מים רבים, לא יותר.
פשר הדבר הוא שיחזקאל נבא בסוף הספר (פרק מז) על הנחל אשר יצא מן המקדש. כאשר השגחת ה' על המים באה בצורת נחל, אין קול ה' קול מפחיד של רעם אלא זה של מים רבים. רק בזמננו, כאשר השגחת ה' על המים באה בצורת המטר, קול ה' הוא קול הרעם מה שיותר אדיר ממים רבים.
יוצא שמתחת לרקיע של יחזקאל היה קול מים רבים. ממעל לרקיע היה מראה קשור גם כן למים- כמראה הקשת אשר יהיה ביום הענן ביום הגשם. זהו המראה אשר ממעל לרקיע, מה ששמע יחזקאל קולו המדבר אליו. ממעל לרקיע אינו מקום הנהרות ומים רבים, אלא מקום הגשם והקשת, וקול המטר.
יוצא שיחזקאל ראה את הרקיע הזה המבדיל.
הרקיע שראה יחזקאל היה כעין הקרח הנורא. לפי זה נראה שהרקיע בתוך המים, איננו באמצע המים מבדיל בין מים למים לבד, אלא שנעשה ממים לחים שהוקרשו ונעשו קרח (ראה ברש"י כאן). הרקיע איננו אלא המים בתוקפם. כל מיני המים אז נמדדים כפי יחסם אל המים האלו התקיפים שנעשו קרח. ישנם מים למטה ממנו, השייכים אל הארץ, ויש מים אדיר במרום למעלה ממנו, יותר מנותקים מן הארץ.

בפרקי דר"א שם אמרו שהרקיע מאיר ומזהיר (כמש"כ והמשכילים יזהירו כזהר הרקיע). כן ביארו מש"כ הקרח הנורא שהוא מבהיק כמרגליות וכקרח. גם בפ"ג שם אמרו שנברא הרקיע מאור לבושיו של ה'. לפי זה הרקיע מאיר. ביארנו לעיל שהמים נהפכו ממים מחשיכים למים מאירים. כאן הרקיע, אמצע ותקפם של המים, נעשה לגוף אחד מאיר, ומזה יש שני מיני מים, אורה, דהיינו הגשמים למעלה, ונהרות ויאורים, דהיינו מים רבים דלמטה. אלו שני מיני מים המאירים הבאים מכח הרקיע. ריבוי המים הבלתי מתוקנים עושים חשך על פני תהום, ואילו הקרשת המים לקרח עושה אורה. 
התהום, בתחלה, איננו קשור אל המים המאירים של קרח הרקיע. רק בסוף הימים יאיר הלויתן את הנתיב הזה הבלתי מואר וידוע, ויחשב תהום לשיבה, ויעשה מן התהום החשוך בצעירותו אור לעת זקנותו. אז גם התהום למטה מן הארץ מואר וקשור אל הרקיע המאיר, וקשור השמים אל הארץ באמת.

Comment: Hello user3095, this answer would be greatly improved if you could translate it for people who do not read Hebrew.